# Регулярное выражение - поиск всех слов длиннее двух букв, которые не равны определенному слову

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть условие: выбрать из текста все слова длиннее двух букв, которые
не равны слову слово. Как написать регулярное выражение под это дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

где то так

```
\b(?!слово\b)\S{2,}\b
```

(это prce). С поддержкой кириллицы посмотрите самостоятельно.

Comment: Может все-таки {3,}, если длиннее 2 букв???

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/dM9eZ9

Comment: может и три. Нужны "тесткейсы" для проверки:).